# I need to set anchor tag center with a media query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm trying to get my brand name to move to the center of the screen using a media query but I don't think I'm doing it right. I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" href="#">Brand Name</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phone</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Email</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Social</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

```
    @media (min-width: 320px)
  .navbar
    text-align: center
```

Comment: Is that the actual CSS you are trying to use?

Comment: Are you using a preprocessor because your CSS rules are not wrapped in `{   }`?

Comment: see my answer @scriptTease

Comment: @DavidG It's actually sass, but yes.

Comment: It's from my sass file. @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please view in mobile view.

`.navbar` has  `justify-content: flex-start` default so you need to change into  `justify-content: center` in mobile.

```css
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .navbar {
        justify-content: center !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" href="#">Brand Name</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phone</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Email</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Social</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! But now how do I set the links under it as well?

Comment: Nvm, I was able to figure it out!